# GitHub/GitLab - use forking to create backup of repository?

Tags: git, backup, git-fork

> Background: I must overwrite my repository to switch to `git lfs`. Before doing so, I want to create a backup of the current state. For now I just created a local copy of the repository and a branch in the migrated repository, that holds the non-lfs state.

What is the best way, to create a backup/copy of the current state of a project? Is it plausible to just fork the project or would that have some negative side-effects?

And how would forking compare to just create a new repository and push the current state?